# React Router print react empty on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am using server side rendering for performance, but my client side diffs from server, because my client renders first `<!-- react-empty: 1 -->` instead of components and then after client detects that checksum is different it re-renders app, so I am losing performance. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424613/react-server-side-rendering-and-lazy-loading-of-webpack) I asked question where described my problem, and after some debugging I found that my `Router` element cause problem here in my root component

```
render() {
    let history = browserHistory;

    if (this.props.store) {
        history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, props.store)
    }

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

when I change `Router` to simple `div` element it renders div, but with Router it doesn't render my elements first, which cause mismatching of checksum and re-rendering on client side.

this is my routes. I have written this way since I am using lazy loading.

```
export default {
    component: App,
    path: '/',
    indexRoute: { onEnter: (nextState, replace) => { replace('/sneakpeak') } },
    childRoutes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            getComponent(location, cb) {
                import('./LightApp')
                  .then(loadRoute(cb))
                  .catch(errorLoading);
            },
            childRoutes: [
                {
                    path: '/sneakpeak',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./SneakPeak')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: '/prespectives',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./Blog')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: '/post(/:id)',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./Post')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: 'users/registration(/:token)',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./SignUp')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: 'users/password/reset(/:token)',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./PasswordReset')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: 'users/posts(/:tab)',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./PostManagement')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: '/terms',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./Terms')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: '/disclaimer',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./Disclaimer')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: '/privacy',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./Privacy')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: '/about',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./About')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: '/faq',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./Faq')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            path: '/',
            getComponent(location, cb) {
                import('./FinancialApp')
                  .then(loadRoute(cb))
                  .catch(errorLoading);
            },
            childRoutes: [
                {
                    path: 'symbol/list/:type(/:letter)',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./SymbolList')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: 'symbol/info/:symbol(/:tab)',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./Symbol')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: 'market(/:tab)',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./Market')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: 'account(/:tab)',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./Account')
                          .then(loadRoute(cb))
                          .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: '*',
                    getComponent(location, cb) {
                        import('./NoMatch')
                              .then(loadRoute(cb))
                              .catch(errorLoading);
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I think my code is right, but if something I am doing wrong please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I found issue and answered to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424613/react-server-side-rendering-and-lazy-loading-of-webpack?noredirect=1&lq=1)
Basically if app sign lazy loading, you should render `Router` component like described [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md#async-routes).